# Arrow keys focuses on fixed position left and does not move relative content right up or down

Tags: javascript, css, html

i have two sections on my html web page. left is fixed position menu and right is relative. My worry is that on navigating to the page, arrow keys dont work to scroll down or up. I'm sure it focuses on the fixed position menu on the left. How can the focus be on the right content that is not fixed so that as soon as you land on the page, you can use the arrow keys to move down and up for the content right? Please can anyone help? thank you

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Comment: Share your code..